# What "Available Software Sites" should I register in LiClipse to upgrade sucessfully?

Tags: eclipse, upgrade, liclipse

I am running LiClipse 7.1.0, in an instance of LiClipse/Eclipse which has been in use and upgraded for a long, long time. LiClipse is now suggesting that I upgrade to LiClipse 7.2.0. When I try to upgrade, it fails with a message, "dependencies are not satisfiable".

Looking at the [LiClipse blog post announcing 7.1.0](https://liclipse.blogspot.com/2020/12/liclipse-710-released-improved-dark.html), I see the statement, "LiClipse is now based on Eclipse 4.17 (2020-09)". The modules needed to support this come from the list of "Available Software Sites" in the Eclipse… Preferences… Install/Update… dialogue. I have entries there of the form, `http://download.eclipse.org/eclipse/updates/4.7` and `http://download.eclipse.org/eclipse/updates/4.14`. I should maybe add an entry like `http://download.eclipse.org/eclipse/updates/4.17` or …`/2020-09` or something.

But which sites should I have in that list of Available Software Sites in order to let LiClipse update successfully? Which URLs do I enter? In the future, what is a way to learn of new URLs to enter, so that the answer isn't specific to this current version of Eclipse?

In the [Eclipse wiki page on "How do I upgrade Eclipse IDE"](http://wiki.eclipse.org/index.php?title=FAQ_How_do_I_upgrade_Eclipse_IDE%3F&redirect=no) I see instructions to "Enter the URL of the new repository", but not a list of repositories to use. I want a list of repositories. I don't want to guess.

I keep hoping to find a page which says, "For LiClipse 7.2.0, use these Available Software Sites". Or better yet, I keep hoping that Eclipse will have a mechanism whereby previous Available Software Sites can tell Eclipse about new Available Software Sites to add, and old ones to retire. But I don't find that.

Below is the error message which LiClipse gives me when I try to upgrade to LiClipse 7.2.0.

```
Cannot complete the install because some dependencies are not satisfiable
  Software being installed: a.jre.javase 1.7.0
  Software being installed: LiClipse 7.2.0.202102221417 (com.brainwy.liclipse.rcp.product 7.2.0.202102221417)
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: LiClipse Editor 7.2.0.202102221417 (com.brainwy.liclipse.editor 7.2.0.202102221417)
    To: osgi.ee; (&(osgi.ee=JavaSE)(version=11))
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: LiClipse Feature 7.2.0.202102221417 (com.brainwy.liclipse.feature.feature.group 7.2.0.202102221417)
    To: org.eclipse.equinox.p2.iu; com.brainwy.liclipse.editor [7.2.0.202102221417,7.2.0.202102221417]
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: LiClipse 7.2.0.202102221417 (com.brainwy.liclipse.rcp.product 7.2.0.202102221417)
    To: org.eclipse.equinox.p2.iu; com.brainwy.liclipse.feature.feature.group [7.2.0.202102221417,7.2.0.202102221417]
```

I am running on MacOS 10.13.6 High Sierra, if that makes a difference.

Answer (score 1):

http://update.liclipse.com/latest (according to https://www.liclipse.com/download.html#update_site).

What the error message is telling you is that you need to run LiClipse using Java 11, which makes sense because Eclipse 4.17 requires Java 11. Note that Eclipse 4.17 isn't tested on anything older than [Mojave](https://www.eclipse.org/projects/project-plan.php?planurl=http://www.eclipse.org/eclipse/development/plans/eclipse_project_plan_4_17.xml#target_environments); you should update to at least that release if you can.

Comment: Thank you. This is helpful information for my problem, but doesn't answer this question about "Available Software Sites". I created a separate question https://stackoverflow.com/q/66514369/1099571 asking how to comprehend the upgrade failure message. This would be a great answer to that question. More explanation of the structure and meaning of such messages would be even better.

Comment: In that case I think http://update.liclipse.com/latest is really all that exists for that. It's only usable as an Update Site, though, not browsable using a web browser, and you might want to use it on conjunction with https://download.eclipse.org/releases/latest .