# How can I comprehend this Liclipse (Eclipse) upgrade failure error message?

Tags: eclipse, upgrade, error-logging, liclipse

I am running LiClipse 7.1.0, in an instance of LiClipse/Eclipse which has been in use and upgraded for a long, long time. LiClipse is now suggesting that I upgrade to LiClipse 7.2.0. When I try to upgrade, it fails with a message, "dependencies are not satisfiable".

Below is the upgrade failure error message which LiClipse gives me. How can I comprehend what it is trying to tell me?  At a surface level, it's clearly trying to say, "you want to install A, A depends on B, for some reason B isn't available". But that interpretation is not sufficient for me to understand what A and B refer to, nor how to solve the problem.

What does the expression "`a.jre.javase 1.7.0`" mean? What does the expression "`osgi.ee`" mean? What does the expression "`(&(osgi.ee=JavaSE)(version=11))`" mean? Is there documentation somewhere that will let me decode these expressions here, and also in the future, in other cases?

```
Cannot complete the install because some dependencies are not satisfiable
  Software being installed: a.jre.javase 1.7.0
  Software being installed: LiClipse 7.2.0.202102221417 (com.brainwy.liclipse.rcp.product 7.2.0.202102221417)
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: LiClipse Editor 7.2.0.202102221417 (com.brainwy.liclipse.editor 7.2.0.202102221417)
    To: osgi.ee; (&(osgi.ee=JavaSE)(version=11))
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: LiClipse Feature 7.2.0.202102221417 (com.brainwy.liclipse.feature.feature.group 7.2.0.202102221417)
    To: org.eclipse.equinox.p2.iu; com.brainwy.liclipse.editor [7.2.0.202102221417,7.2.0.202102221417]
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: LiClipse 7.2.0.202102221417 (com.brainwy.liclipse.rcp.product 7.2.0.202102221417)
    To: org.eclipse.equinox.p2.iu; com.brainwy.liclipse.feature.feature.group [7.2.0.202102221417,7.2.0.202102221417]
```

I am running on MacOS 10.13.6 High Sierra, if that makes a difference.

[LiClipse](https://www.liclipse.com/) is a distribution of the [Eclipse](http://eclipse.org/) IDE with some Python programming extras included. I suspect the structure of this error message is from Eclipse, not modified by LiClipse. Thus an answer describing how to comprehend Eclipse upgrade failure messages is welcome, even if you don't know LiClipse.

Comment: `osgi.ee; (&(osgi.ee=JavaSE)(version=11))` is saying it needs at least Java 11

Comment: `(&(osgi.ee=JavaSE)(version=11))` means Java 11 or higher is required. Does installing a Java JRE 15 _Complete_ via the update site [`https://download.eclipse.org/justj/jres/15/updates/`](https://download.eclipse.org/justj/jres/15/updates/) solve your problem?

Comment: @greg-449 @howlger I believe you that Java 11 is required. See related question https://stackoverflow.com/q/66514535/1099571 where I try to figure out how to add Java 11 to a LiClipse instance. But beyond just solving my problem today, this question asks for help understanding these messages in general. Where would one learn that `(&(osgi.ee=JavaSE)(version=11))` means "Java 11"? Care to expand these comments into answers?

Comment: These messages are from the p2 provisioning code. There is a bit about that in the Eclipse Help and a number of Eclipse Wiki page [here](https://wiki.eclipse.org/Category:Equinox_p2), not sure if there is anything better anywhere.

Comment: By following my comment you will install the required Java as embedded part of your LiClipse/Eclipse. IMHO LiClipse should be shipped with that Java, which would prevent the issue you face.

Comment: @greg-449, thank you for the link. Perhaps if someone would find the right article(s) from that Wiki category listing, and write an explanation of the messages, that would turn into a really good answer to this question.

Comment: @howlger This question is about comprehending the messages, not about fixing the upgrade problem. Another question, https://stackoverflow.com/q/66514535/1099571 , is about upgrading the JRE which LiClipse uses. Maybe you will make an answer about `justj/jres/15` there? Yes, LiClipse includes its own JRE, but my instance is an old one which I installed years ago with a past JRE.

Comment: `a.jre.javase` refers to the Java used to run Eclipse. LiClipse Editor 7.2.0.202102221417 requires the OSGi execution environment (`osgi.ee`) [Java Standard Edition](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/) (`JavaSE`) of version 11 or higher (`version=11`). See https://docs.osgi.org/reference/eenames.html