# How can I update the Java environment for LiClipse on macOS?

Tags: java, macos, java-11, liclipse

I am running LiClipse 7.1.0, in an instance of LiClipse/Eclipse which has been in use and upgraded for a long, long time. Looking at the [Release Highlights for LiClipse 7.1.0](https://www.liclipse.com/), I see the statement, "Updated to Eclipse 2020-09 (4.17). Java 11 is now required."

[Update] Also, an upgrade to this LiClipse installation is failing. Error messages mention "`Cannot satisfy dependency: …To: osgi.ee; (&(osgi.ee=JavaSE)(version=11))`". I am told that means LiClipse requires Java 11 in order to upgrade successfully. (See [How can I comprehend this Liclipse (Eclipse) upgrade failure error message?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66514369/1099571) for more on that error message.)

My version of Java is older than 11:

```
% java -version
java version "1.8.0_31"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_31-b13)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.31-b07, mixed mode)
% /usr/libexec/java_home
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_31.jdk/Contents/Home
```

I think that means I have "Java 8" (I'm not clear on the Java version numbering scheme, and the relationship between "jdk1.x" and "Java X", etc.)

We know that LiClipse contains its own Java Runtime Environment (JRE). See [Does LiClipse (for Mac) include its own copy of the JRE?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47549726/1099571) . Answer: "Yes, LiClipse does include a JRE (depending on each platform it may be on a different place)." On the macOS builds, "The [Java Home](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27716151/1099571) directory for this JRE is within the `LiClipse.app` bundle directory, at `./jre/Contents/Home`." [Update] The version of LiClipse's own JRE is also 1.8, not 1.11. That isn't surprising, because this instance of LiClipse has been in use and upgraded for a long time.

```
% cd /Applications/LiClipse\ 4.0.0/LiClipse.app/jre/Contents/Home
% /Applications/LiClipse\ 4.0.0/LiClipse.app/jre/Contents/Home/bin/java -version
java version "1.8.0_77"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_77-b03)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.77-b03, mixed mode)
```

So, how best to upgrade the JRE which LiClipse uses? If I run the Oracle Java installer, I expect it will put the JRE in a system location, not inside the `LiClipse.app` bundle directory.

I am running on MacOS 10.13.6 High Sierra, if that makes a difference. For some reason I am able to run LiClipse 7.1.0, even though I am not running Java 11.

[Question updated to add reason why I want to upgrade the JRE which LiClipse uses, and to show that the internal JRE is not Java 11.]

Comment: Are you sure you have to install anything? The FAQ you linked to says that LiClipse ships with its own JRE (so that it does not need Java to be installed separately at all). What issues are you running into?

Comment: @Thilo, thank you for the comment. I updated the question to clarify those aspects. Yes, I need to update the JRE which LiClipse uses, because the JRE is an old version and it blocks a software upgrade. Remember, I first installed this instance of LiClipse (and its built-in JRE) a long time ago.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my search for an answer to my question, I found no direct way to update the JRE within LiClipse via user-accessible techniques. I did find a two-step workaround: install a new, separate instance of LiClipse having the newer JRE, then update that installation based on the previous LiClipse installation.

The steps are:

1. Quit from the old version of LiClipse.
2. Be sure that your existing
   workspace directory is backed up. What you are about to do should
   not, in theory, harm it. But in practice, things do go wrong. You do
   back up your computers every hour or so anyway, correct?
3. From the
   [LiClipse download page](https://www.liclipse.com/download.html#macos), download the installer for the new version
   of LiClipse.
4. Install the new version of LiClipse, being sure that
   it does not replace the previous version of LiClipse.
5. Run the new
   version of LiClipse, by right-clicking on its application icon, and
   selecting "Open" from the popup menu.

   a. If you see an error message, '"LiClipse.app" is damaged and can't be opened. You should move it to the Trash.', then perform
   these commands from the Terminal:

   ```
   xattr -d com.apple.quarantine /Applications/LiClipse.app
   xattr -d com.apple.quarantine /Applications/LiClipse.app/Contents/MacOS/LiClipse
   ```

   (For more on why, see [LiClipse macOS installation instructions](https://www.liclipse.com/download.html#macos).)

   b. Then try again: Run the new version of LiClipse, by right-clicking on its application icon, and selecting "Open" from
   the popup menu.
6. LiClipse will prompt you to select a directory to serve as the
   workspace. Point it at your existing workspace directory.
7. LiClipse
   may warn you that it will upgrade your workspace, and old versions
   of Eclipse won't be able to use it anymore. Accept the upgrade.
   (This is one moment when you are glad to have a backup of the
   workspace.) LiClipse opens.
8. In LiClipse, select menu option **File… Import…** The Import dialogue appears.
9. Select the folder **Install** from
   that dialogue. Items appear under **Install**. Select **From Existing
   Installation**.
10. Click the "Next >" button, The Import from
    Application dialogue appears.
11. At the field, "From application
    installation", click the "Browse…" button. A File Open dialogue
    appears.
12. Navigate to the application icon for the previous version
    of LiClipse. Click the "Open" button. The File Open dialogue
    disappears. A list of Eclipse components appears in the lower part
    of the Import from Application dialogue. These are the components
    used by the previous copy of LiClipse.
13. Select those components which
    you want to import and use in the new version of LiClipse. (I
    selected all of them.) Complete the installation process as normal.
    You return to the main LiClipse application.
14. Just to confirm, select
    menu item **Help… Check for Updates**. Update anything else offered
    which you wish to take. (There were none for me.) You should not
    encounter the "Cannot complete the install because some dependencies
    are not satisfiable" error message.
15. Delete the old installation of LiClipse.

You have now successfully updated the JRE in LiClipse.

This answer is adapted from my blog post, [*How to update the JRE in LiClipse*](http://blog.jdlh.com/en/2021/05/28/update-jre-liclipse/) (2021-05-28). There is a little more background explanation there.